# Angular 7 observable wait for variable to be false

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, observable, angular7

The following observable:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    readonly loginUrl = <login_url>;
    readonly authStatusUrl = <auth_status_url>;
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private cookieService: CookieService) {}

loggingIn = false;

login(username: string, password: string) {
    this.loggingIn = true;
    const creds = {
        username: username,
        password: password
    };
    this.http
    .post<any>(this.loginUrl, creds, {})
    .subscribe(
        data => this.onLoginSuccess(data),
        error => this.onLoginFail(error));
}

handleAuth(): Observable<any> {

    const token = this.cookieService.get('token');
    const refresh = this.cookieService.get('refresh');

    // should wait for loggingIn to be false
    return this.http
        .post<any>(this.authStatusUrl, { }, {
            headers: {
                token: token,
                refresh: refresh
            }
        });
}

public onLoginSuccess(data) {
    this.loggingIn = false;
    this.cookieService.set('token', data.access_token);
    this.cookieService.set('refresh', data.refresh_token);
}

onLoginFail(err) {
    console.log('Faild to login');
    this.loggingIn = false;
}
```

}

should not be executed until a local variable is false.

I read that this should be done using Promises and async function call with await operator, but I could not find something that will poll for the variable value, only 'wait for some time and the resolve'.

The main idea is to call handleAuth and internally it should assure that login is not in progress, by waiting for the local variable (or something to happen)

Comment: post the local variable and code

Comment: maybe use a setter on this local variable ?

Comment: Added the whole code

Comment: IMO: I would ask about how to refresh a token when it expires rather than asking very broadly about this technical solution you have picked.

Comment: Why dont you call the function handleAuth(), where you are setting this.loggingIn = false;

Comment: @Gimby the login and the refresh are working fine, problem is if login is in progress and authStatus is called I get Unauthorized, because is it using the old values

Comment: @BorislavStoilov don't you need `handleAuth` to execute at the end of `onLoginSuccess`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a setter on the local variable for this purpose :

```
private _localVariable;


set localVariable(value) {
  this._localVariable = value;
  if(this._localVariable) {
   //call your function here.
  }
}
```

Comment: I am calling handleAuth in guard, and problem arises if user is currently being logged in.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is making `loggingIn` a `Subject`, push the "done" event into the `loggingIn` and then `flatMap` `loggingIn` into the `http.post`.

Comment: So in conclusion it is way easier to handle asyncronous events if all of them are `Observables`.

Comment: I can provide further explaination / code samples if needed.

Comment: I created the subject:
this is how I piped it to the http.post
.pipe(mergeMap(this.loggingInSubject.asObservable))

on login I do this.loggingInSubject.next(true);
and on login success/fail this.loggingInSubject.next();

but I get error now  source.subscribe is not a function

Comment: you need to call `asObservable()` as a function.